# Automated mapping of cost paths from multiple origin points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, cost-path, arcgis-10.5

I am currently mapping Lahar flows on Montserrat Island (as many have done before!). I have the Cost Distance analysis below, the circle is the origin and the triangle the destination. With a known destination a Cost Path analysis can easily be performed, however I would like to use the Cost Distance map below to *automatically* find the destination point, based purely on the the direction of flow from the origin/circle.

I was thinking of using a filter to include only edge cells of the raster, and then find the one with the lowest value, is there a way to do this?

Software: Arc GIS Desktop 10.5

[image: Montserrat]

Comment: What are the components of your cost surface apart from elevation?

Comment: I intend to add in vegetation cover next, but currently the cost surface is solely the DEM of the island.

Comment: It makes it purely hydrochlorical task. Fill dem, compute flow direction. Create small buffer around lake. Place multiple points on buffer to simulate different outburst locations. Compute cost paths from these points using flow direction as back link, anything as cost

Comment: Excellent instructions thank you, however my cost paths only extend a short distance and then stop, should they not go to the edge of the raster (ie. the ocean in this case)?

Comment: Fill Dem first to remove sinks

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! If you would like to leave your comments in the form of an answer I will gladly accept it and award you with the points (not that you seem to be needing them)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53834/discussion-between-felixip-and-sam3000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With elevation being single component of cost surface, the task is purely hydrological and can be saved by using relevant Spatial Analyst toolbox.

- Fill elevation model to remove sinks
- Compute flow direction
- Create small buffer around lake and place multiple points on buffer
  to simulate different outburst locations.
- Compute cost paths from these points using flow direction as back
  link, anything as cost.
- Convert stream to feature (optional)

Input:
[image]

Output:

[image]